# Visualforce Page Update Failed when saving directly to production

Tags: salesforcedx

Trying to save a VF page directly to production, receiving this error:

"Saving... Visualforce Page Update Failed ✖"

everything appears setup fine. Refresh/compare from server work fine. The output table for line/column/description are blank

Any ideas? I was hoping to be able to save VF pages directly to production to save time on VF only pages

**EDIT** -checking the log I see:

{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Work","pid":29956,"log":"Set","level":50,"msg":"[\n  '\x1B[1mERROR running config:set: \x1B[22m',\n  '\x1B[31mSetting variables must be in the format = or ="" but found Bob.\x1B[39m'\n]","time":"2021-11-23T11:36:58.213Z","v":0}

where would I find this setting to correct? I've searched with nothing found for this value "Bob"

Comment: The to directly save the vf page in your production without using the IDE

Comment: In the bash script, type `tail ~/.sfdx/sfdx.log` and see what the errors are there. If you want to [edit] your question to include the details here, we'll be happy to help you out.